# Is this theorem provable using relatively elementary number theory and abstract algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, galois-theory

$\textbf{Theorem}$: Let $p$ be a prime. Let $q$ be a prime that doesn't divide $p - 1$, so that $\mathbb{F}_p$ does not have an element of order $q$. Let $\zeta$ be an imaginary number whose order is $q$. Then:

1. The polynomial $x^{q - 1} + x^{q - 2} + \cdots + x + 1$ is one with the smallest degree which $\zeta$ satisfies.
2. $\mathbb{F}_p(\zeta)$ is a field with $p^{q - 1}$ elements.
3. All elements in $\mathbb{F}_p(\zeta)$ are in the following form, and they are all distinct: $a_0 + a_1\zeta + a_2\zeta^2 + \cdots + a_{q - 2}\zeta^{q - 2}.$

My professor gave us this theorem in our elementary number theory class and when I asked him how the proof goes, he said that it can be proven using Galois Theory (which we don't know yet) but that it might be solvable using what we already know (which is a 1 semester's worth of number theory and 1-2 semesters worth of abstract algebra).

If this is provable using what I already know (elementary number theory and abstract algebra), could I get a hint on what direction to go in to prove this?

Comment: Do you know Eisenstein's criterion?

Comment: Your question confuses me because you refer to $\zeta$ as an *imaginary number* yet seem to be working over the field $\Bbb F_p$.  Do you mean to say that $\zeta \ne \Bbb F_p$, i.e. $\zeta$ lies in some extension field of $\Bbb F_p$?  $\zeta$ is not a number, real or complex, in the usual sense in that event.  It's OK, but I'm not really familiar with that usage.  Any clarifying remarks would be appreciated.  Cheers.

Comment: Hey Robert - Yes, by imaginary we just mean a number not in $\mathbb{F}_p$, not a complex number. An example we used recently was an element of order 5 in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Ian Coley - While we haven't talked about Eisenstein's Criteria, I looked it up in my Dummit and Foote book and it seems like something I could handle at my level.